# Device to device copy in Vulkan

Tags: c++, gpu, vulkan

I want to copy an image/buffer between two GPUs/physical devices in my Vulkan application (one `vkInstance`, two `vkDevice`s). Is this possible without staging the image on the CPU or is there a feature like CUDA p2p? How would this look?

If staging on the host is required, what would be the optimal method for this?

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there a feature like CUDA p2p?

Vulkan 1.1 supports the concept of [device groups](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/master/appendices/VK_KHR_device_group.txt) to cover this situation. 
 It allows you to treat a set of physical devices as a single logical device, and also lets you query how memory can be manipulated within the device group, as well as do things like allocate memory on a subset of devices.  Check the specifications for the full set of functionality.

> Is this possible without staging the image on the CPU

If your devices don't support the extenson `VK_KHR_device_group`, then no.  You must transfer the content through the CPU and system memory.

Since buffers are per-device, you would need two host-visible staging buffers, one for the read operation, and another for the write operation.  You'll also need two queues, two command buffers, etc, etc...

You'll have to execute 3 operations with manual synchronization.

- On the source GPU execute a copy from the device-local buffer to the host visible buffer for the same device.
- On the CPU copy from the source GPU host visible buffer to the target GPU host-visible buffer
- On the target GPU copy from the host-visible buffer to the device-local buffer

Make sure to inspect your device queue family properties and if possible use a queue from a queue family that is marked as transfer capable but *not* graphics or compute capable.  The fewer flags a Vulkan queue family has, the better suited it is to the operations that it *does* have flags for.  Most [modern discrete GPUs](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/) have dedicated transfer queues, but again, queues are specific to devices, so you'll need to be interacting with one queue for each device to execute the transfer.

> If staging on the host is required, what would be the optimal method for this?

Exactly how to execute this depends on your use case.  If you want to execute the whole thing synchronously in a single thread, then you'll just be doing a bunch of submits and then waiting on fences.  If you want to do it asynchronously in the background while you continue to render frames, then you'll still be doing the submits, but you'll have to non-blocking checking on the fences to see when operations complete before you move to the next part.

If you're transferring buffers there's probably nothing to be worried about in terms of optimal transfer, but if you're dealing with images then you have to get into the whole linear vs optimal image tiling mess.  In order to avoid that I'd suggest using host visible buffers for staging, regardless of whether you're transferring images or buffers, and as such use `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` and `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage` to do the transfers between device-local and host-visible memory

Comment: "*Device to device copying may be supported if the devices are bound together in some fashion like SLI.*" Technically, shared external memory can be used for non-SLI cases. But this requires that both devices are identical hardware (`deviceUUID` and `driverUUID` must match). That is, you don't have to *use them* as SLI devices, but they have to have theoretically be *able* to be used that way.

Comment: Yeah, I re-read my stuff and realized I might be implying that SLI was required when I meant it just as a potential example, so I edited that out of my response.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Jherico Awesome, this is just what I was looking for. Are there any caveats when using `VK_KHR_external_memory` since it doesn't allow you to share memory on separate physical devices? I'm interfacing with an OpenGL application that's running a separate instance per GPU.

Comment: You just need to match up the GL contexts to the appropriate Vulkan devices using by querying for `DEVICE_UUID_EXT` and `DRIVER_UUID_EXT` on the GL side.  Bear in mind that I have not been able to get interoperability to work on my AMD system due to bugs in their implementation of `GL_EXT_external_objects`.  I'm currently working on an OpenGL interoperability example here:  https://github.com/jherico/Vulkan/blob/gl_test2/examples/glinterop/glinterop.cpp